# How to check why there is a lag loading the stylesheet for website

Tags: ruby, performance

I'm building a website and there seems to be a lag with loading the stylesheets.  It seems as if the page loads without the stylesheet and then a few seconds later (depending on the network speed) the entire page loads.  This would of course be a bad experience for the users.  I can't figure out what stylesheet is not loading quickly to cause this delay.  Here are the links.

http://www.hotelzoo.com/sign_up?hotelregister=true
http://www.hotelzoo.com/sign_in

I'm coding this using Ruby, Heroku, and AWS if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the performance with a tool like the [Timeline in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)?

Answer (score 3):

You're importing the CSS in the bottom of the page, together with the JavaScript but it shouldn't be there. Always import the CSS inside the `<header>` tag at beginning, this way the browser will load the source files before rendering the page.